# tkinter <KeyRelease> different behavior on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, tkinter, cross-platform, keyrelease

In my CS class, my students just finished their first "clone your classic" contest. The `PONG` team went rapidly through the "Hey my paddle is frozen" issue with their two players on one keyboard version. I came across this problem 5 years ago and found [Python bind - allow multiple keys to be pressed simultaniously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138518/python-bind-allow-multiple-keys-to-be-pressed-simultaniously/2141044#2141044) that enlightened me (watch out ! The article uses python2.7). But I didn't realize then that the script only worked on windows machines.

On a linux system, the `<KeyRelease-a>` event triggers the callback, but the `event.char` then points to ' ' and not 'a' as one could expect. I tried googling the issue, but even on `stackoverflow` I couldn't find anything  of interest.

Any hints? Next find the reproducible code sample:

```
import os
from tkinter import *

os.system("xset r off")

def keyup(e):
    #print(f"up {e.char}")
    print(f"up {e.keysym}")

def keydown(e):
    #print(f"down {e.char}")
    print(f"down {e.keysym}")

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()

os.system("xset r on")
```

for reproducibility as asked by Bryan, which I thank for his concern about my question.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]. It shouldn't take but a dozen lines or so.

Comment: ``import os
from tkinter import *

os.system("xset r off")

def keyup(e):
    print(f"up {e.char}")

def keydown(e):
    print(f"down {e.char}")

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()

os.system("xset r on")``

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section. If you're trying to add additional information, please [edit] the question.

Comment: Have you tried `e.keysym` ? they use *keysym* in the [offical tcl documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M58).

Comment: @Atlas435 Thank you very much, e.keysym did the job allright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the subject, all the job has been done by Atlas435 : if you want to code a Pong with Tkinter, with two paddles listening independently to the keystrokes, follow this post [Python bind - allow multiple keys to be pressed simultaniously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138518/python-bind-allow-multiple-keys-to-be-pressed-simultaniously/2141044#2141044) but change `e.char` into `e.keysym` in the callbacks to get which key triggered the event Pressed or Released.